# Allow http request over specific port in iptables

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, port, wireshark

I'm running Kodi with a web service for the remote control. The web server is listening to port 11734, however opening that port (UDP and TCP) doesn't seem to work. Once I accept all incoming traffic it works fine.

I tried wiresharking the packets to see what was actually going on. The remote control app that I use sends an RPC request over HTTP (which should be port 80).

In wireshark the src port is listed as 49609 and the destination as 11734. I'm kinda lost which port I should open now. Any ideas?

Solved: I had to open the event server port: 9777

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be that the event server port was not opened. That port is 9777